# Is there a way to rename keywords in c# for custom ones?

Tags: c#, rename, project, keyword

As a fun project and making some people laugh, I want to create a project that renames keywords such as true and false into something funnier in C#.

For example, replace True with Yass

How would I go about doing something like this? I saw stuff like that in JS, and I know you can do it in Python as well.

Comment: You could also write a [source generator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/using-c-source-generators-to-create-an-external-dsl/) to translate your new made-up syntax to valid C#

Comment: Do you need the original keywords to not "work" anymore or do you not care? If the latter, then investigating "domain specific languages" may be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a constant: `const bool Yass = true;`

---

You can also prefix a keyword by `@` to make it an identifier:

```cs
// Just for fun
const bool @true = false;
const bool @false = true;
```

But you will have to use the `@` every time when using these constants. You cannot really change the built-in keywords in C# but [contextual keywords](https://www.codeindotnet.com/csharp-keywords-reserved-contextual/) can be used as valid identifiers outside of their context.

And since keywords and identifiers are case sensitive in C#, you can declare

```cs
const bool True = false;
const bool False = true;
```

---

You can also do fun stuff with [Operator overloading - predefined unary, arithmetic, equality and comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) and let them do unexpected things.

---

A very surprising possibility is to let a class implement [true and false operators - treat your objects as a Boolean value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/true-false-operators):

```cs
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static bool operator true(Person p) => p.Name == "Yass";
    public static bool operator false(Person p) => p.Name != "Yass";
}
```

Now, persons are treated as Boolean values.

You can test it like this:

```cs
public static void Test()
{
    var p1 = new Person { Name = "Fizz" };
    var p2 = new Person { Name = "Yass" };

    if (p1) {
        Console.WriteLine("p1 is true");
    }
    if (p2) {
        Console.WriteLine("p2 is true");
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```